# What household servants would a Tudor gentleman have had?

Tags: england, 16th-century, social-class, tudor-period

There's a lot of easily-accessible information about the staffing of a Tudor nobleman's household, but very little about that of a Tudor gentleman's.

Was it basically the same as a nobleman's? Or would there be significantly fewer servants?

Was there a smaller proportion of gentlemen servants and a greater proportion of yeoman servants and grooms? Would there be any gentlemen servants at all, or would

(By "gentleman" I mean a wealthy land-owner (usually 200 acres or more, including a dozen or more manors), who presides over manor-courts and doesn't do any manual work himself, but who doesn't hold any aristocratic title; or the son of such a wealthy land-owner).

Answer (score 4):

Suggest you start here: P.W. FLEMING, Household Servants of the Yorkist and Early Tudor Gentry, in: Daniel WILLIAMS (ed.), Early Tudor England (Harlaxton Medieval Studies, O.S., 4), Woodbridge 1989, pp. 19-36

Comment: I really resent being downvoted anonymously for having answered a question which no-one else had bothered to respond to for 3 years. My reply was a perfectly clear academic reference. The principle of all StackExchange fora is that the person posting is expected to do some work in order to reach the final answer. This is supposed to be a site for historians not a substitute for Wikipedia. So I'm not going to summarise the chapter. If anyone is interested, they can easily get it from a library. Perhaps the person who downvoted me would have the courtesy to leave a public comment next time.

Comment: Here's the reason for my upvote: a relevant reference is at least infinitely better than nothing; and when I say infinitely, I really mean infinitely.

Comment: Good answer. Bad attitude. If you resent anonymous downvotes, SE is not going to be comfortable for you. I have an equal resentment for those who demand that all votes be public to enable shaming and harassment of anyone with an opinion. That said, I wholeheartedly agree that your reference is good, valuable, proper and appropriate. Hence my upvote.

Comment: While you don't need to summarize the entire chapter, even a single sentence like "it could range from 1 or 2 to scores" or "a gentleman an a nobleman with the same amount of land would have had the same number of servants" or even "it's too complicated to generalize about" would go a long way to making this a fantastic answer - currently it's a good one.

Comment: I have down-voted you. You don't answer the question. The question isn't "where can I find out how many...". The question is "how many...". If you took the time to do what you say you won't, you would _actually answer the question asked._ As it is, this is one more (attempted) answer than existed before, but ... it is still not _an_ answer to the question asked. It would be trivial for you to both answer it _and_ provide the source where you derived your answer _from_. Then I would not only up-vote you, but probably also give you bonus points for doing it so long after the question was asked.

Comment: As it is, this book may not even answer the question asked. In that case, you would have wasted the OP's time, as well as anyone else who does read it. As it happens, I plan on seeing if my local library has it, just so I can read it.

Comment: I downvoted this as not an answer. It would be a helpful comment, but as it is it simply doesn't answer the question that is asked.  It is significantly worse than a link-only answer, since at least links can be readily checked, and link-only answers are strongly deprecated. "*Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*"

Comment: Any response which provides some assistance to the person asking the question is of at least some value. If the answer does not assist, or if the answer misleads then it should be down-voted. This answer does not really provide enough to be up-voted, but nor does it deserve to be down-voted. Maybe ThomasDoe didn't make much of an effort, but it's still more than anyone else.

Comment: @ThomasDoe i up-voted you as i thought it _was helpful_ however I do also agree that it is not an answer as it only invites the OP to research harder.